# How many steps monkey needs to reach water level?

Tags: word-problem

A monkey is at the topmost of the ladder ... (that is at first step) .and his aim is to reach at ninth step which is the water level...he performs this- he jumps forward three steps and then jumps backward 2 steps .. in how many jumps he would reach the water level ???....

I got by calculating that it is 30 steps but the answer is 11, I don't understand how it is ..

Comment: The sequence is: 1-4-2-5-3-6-4-7-5-8-6-9.  There are 11 dashes (jumps) in all.

Comment: Every two jumps the monkey nets one step closer to his goal.  However, there comes a time when he has reached his goal and doesn't need to jump back any more.

Comment: Once the monkey reached the $6^{th}$ step, he will get to the $9^{th}$ in one single jump, since he has no reason to jump back any longer. Now, there are $5$ steps between the $1^{st}$ and the $6^{th}$, each of which take two jumps, plus the final one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On forward jump and backward jump can make monkey go one step forward, then he needs 5 round which means 5 forward jumps and 5 backward jumps (10 jumps total) to the sixth step, then plus last jump to reach the 9th step.

Answer (score 0):

Destination step is always forward so last step is 3 forward. means before destination it was on 6th step and for reaching on 6th step it requires 5 couples of attempt.
So 5*2+1=11.
3-2=1 step

Answer (score 0):

The Answer Is 11. Because As @snehal Patel mentioned, the Destination step is always forward so the last step is 3 forward. means before destination it was on 6th step and for reaching on 6th step it requires 5 couples of attempt. So ***`5*2+1=11. 3-2=1 steps`***. This would be the correct answer